# How to parse POST data in a CGI script with BASH scripting?

Tags: bash, parsing, cgi

I Have a cgi script written with bash and i have to read a POST variable sent to this file.
I am not good at bash scripting so i really need this help.

From a php script I send a POST variable named log_message to this cgi but i don't know how to parse the POST var from the header.

Any help?

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? Also show what the data looks like.

Comment: i found solution with tr and sed commands i only had to do something similar to urldecode ^^

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919755/how-to-parse-query-string-from-a-bash-cgi-script.

Answer (score 1):

those seds should all have a `g`, as in:

```
sed 's/whatever/whatever/**g**'
```

otherwise it stops after the first replace, which is not generally the desired behaviour.