# how to extract the data using sed command

Tags: linux, sed, html-lists

I have the data this

```
&mac=1E-30-6C-A2-47-5F&ip=172.16.1.127&msk=255.255.255.0&gw=172.16.1.1&pdns=0.0.0.0&sdns=0.0.0.0&Speed=0&PortNo=10001&PerMatFram=0&ComPort=0
```

I want to extract the data string and store it in a variable using sed commond like

```
ip=172.16.1.127
mac=xyz
```

How to use sed with the above string?

I have tried using like this

```
IP=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n '/&ip=/,/&)/g'
```

but it is not giving any data.

Answer (score 0):

If you data do not contain any special characters, you can use the following:

```
eval $( echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed 's/&/ /g' )
```

That would create variables directly from the query string as `mac=1E-30-6C-A2-47-5F` etc. Be careful, though, as an attacker might request a page with the following query string:

```
&IFS=.&PWD=/&UID=0
```

See also [How to parse $QUERY_STRING from a bash CGI script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3919755/1030675).

Comment: I dont want use array just directly I want to extract the value and assign it to a variable like as i said ip=172.16.1.125

Comment: I have tried but the result was NULL it was not printing any thing

Comment: @amar: It does not print anything. It assigns the variables. You have to add `echo $mac` and similar to get the output.

Comment: I Got the out put by using user2234712's suggestion thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to do it in two steps, first trimming the left side, and then the right side.

```
sed 's/.*mac=//' | sed 's/\&.*//'
```

This will:
Step 1:
 Replace anything up until (and including) "mac=" with nothing
Step 2:
 Replace anything after (and including) the first ampersand (&) it encounters with nothing.