# Can i run protractor e2e test from the UI

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to run e2e test case from the UI.

Use case: i will build one testing page on our dev stack, where anyone can run the protractor test case by click on "run" button.

We have created a shell script (run.sh) where we have mentioned to run webdriver-manager start and protractor conf.js, so i guess we just need to run shell script from the UI.

Comment: I did something like this with Jasmine. Haven't used Protractor so not sure how similar it will be. For my Jasmine tests I created a simple HTML page with links to all of the JS files in the following order: Jasmine, libraries (jQuery and AngularJS), sources under test, tests. This setup executes the tests whenever the page is loaded.

Comment: I need to add buttons like run core test, run mobile test and click on that will actually run test on dev stack

Comment: If run-on-load works with Protractor like it does with Jasmine, you could have a parent page that loads the appropriate child (run-on-load) page into an iframe. The child pages would include only the tests you want to run.

Comment: You can easily create a java window with a button on it and specify the path of shell script file to run once you click on it.

Comment: Can you give any lead on the solution? any link? @GirishSortur

Comment: I have implement that using node.js

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765755/run-bash-file-from-web-page), you can create a PHP webpage and use [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to trigger your shell scripts.

Another alternative: my team runs protractor tests via a [Hubot](https://hubot.github.com/) integration in [Slack](https://slack.com/).