# Associative array from querystring in bash?

Tags: bash, query-string, associative-array, bash4, ifs

How do I get an associative array from a query string in Bash? - Attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Querystring (implementation stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/q/3919755)

function populate_querystring_array ()
{
    param="$1"
    query_dict="$2"
    #for i in "${array[@]}"; do IFS="=" ; set -- $i; query_dict[$1]=$2; done

    for ((i=0; i<${#param[@]}; i+=2))
    do
        query_dict[${param[i]}]=${param[i+1]}
    done
}

q0='email=foo@bar.com&password=dfsa54'
declare -A querydict
populate_querystring_array "$q0" "$querydict"
printf "$querydict[email]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

function qrystring() {
    qry=$1

    while read key value; do
        arr+=(["$key"]="$value")
    done < <(awk -F'&' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' <<< $qry | awk -F'=' '{print $1" "$2}')
}

q='email=foo@bar.com&password=dfsa54'
declare -A arr

qrystring "$q"

for k in ${!arr[@]}; do
    echo "$k -> ${arr[$k]}"
done
```

Explanation:

Im using a combination of awk commands to split the string into individual records first, then split on the = sign for kv pair.

I'm using process substitution here otherwise i would be populating a copy of the array.

**EDIT:**

Using a global variable to house array.

Comment: Tim and @AT, just a minor point: you may want to remove the statement `arr=$2`.  This is because,when bash executes the statement `qrystring "$q" "$arr"`, the second argument evaluates to an empty string (because `arr` is empty at that point).  Consequently, the assignment statement  `arr=$2` sets `arg[0]` (`0` is the default index when none is specified) to an empty string.  The effect of this is visible in the final `for` loop which outputs, as one of its lines, the string `0 ->`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
q0='email=foo@bar.com&password=dfsa54'
declare -A querydict
while IFS== read key value
do
    querydict["$key"]="$value"
done < <(echo "$q0" | sed 's/&/\n/g' )
printf "${querydict[email]}\n"
```

In the above, `'s/&/\n/g'` is a `sed` command that replaces every occurrence of `&` with a new line.  We apply this to `q0` so that every parameter assignment is on a separate line.  The parameter assignments are then read into the `while` loop.  To read each assignment, `IFS== read key value` is used.  `IFS==` tells `read` to treat the equal sign as a word separator.  Thus, each assignment is broken into two words: the first is the key and the second is the value.  These are then assigned to the associative array `querydict` with the statement `querydict["$key"]="$value"`.

#### Putting it in a function

`bash` differs from most modern programming languages in that its facilities for passing complex data into and out of functions are extremely limited.  In the method shown below, the associative array, `querydict`, is a global variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A querydict
populate_querystring_array () {
    query="$1"
    while IFS== read arg value
    do 
        querydict["$arg"]="$value"
    done < <(echo "$query" | sed 's/&/\n/g' )
}

q0='email=foo@bar.com&password=dfsa54'
populate_querystring_array "$q0"
printf "${querydict[email]}\n"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get that to work in a function. [See ideone](http://ideone.com/uQ6Pwm).

Comment: @AT `bash` is much more primitive than you think.  Facilities that you may expect from other programming languages are just not part of `bash`.  I did add a `bash` solution with a function to the answer but note that it uses a shared global variable.

Comment: Would rather a passed argument. If that's not possible, I can empty querydict using `unset $querydict`; right? - EDIT: looks like there's [a hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8879444/587021) to make it work

Comment: @AT If you use `unset`, you will lose the `declare -A` definition.  If you just want to empty it, use `querydict=()`.  That hack that you link to uses `eval` which is something people work hard to avoid.  Why is it that you so strongly want to put that simple four line loop in a function?

Comment: Because I need that functionality in a large number of places.

Answer (score 0):

Taking @John1024's answer I use it in a function which returns the associative array by value, simply printing out the contents using array syntax:

```
function parseQuery {
    local querystring="$*"
    echo -n "("
    echo "${querystring}" | sed 's/&/\n/g' | while IFS== read arg value
    do
        echo -n "[${arg}]='${value}' "
    done
    echo ")"
}

declare -A querydict=$(parseQuery "${QUERY_STRING}" )
```