# String manipulation via script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to get a substring between `&DEST=` and the next `&` or a line break.
For example :

1. `MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SFO&ORIG=6546`

   In this I need to extract "SFO"
2. `MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SANFRANSISCO&ORIG=6546`

   In this I need to extract "SANFRANSISCO"
3. `MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHISWITH&DEST=SANJOSE`

   In this I need to extract "SANJOSE"

I am reading a file line by line, and I need to update the text after `&DEST=` and put it back in the file. The modification of the text is to mask the dest value with X character.

So, SFO should be replaced with XXX.
SANJOSE should be replaced with XXXXXXX.

Output : 
`MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=XXX&ORIG=6546`
`MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=XXXXXXXXXXXX&ORIG=6546`
`MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHISWITH&DEST=XXXXXXX`

Please let me know how to achieve this in script (Preferably shell or bash script).

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to [parse a query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919755/how-to-parse-query-string-from-a-bash-cgi-script)?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for replying. I am actually reading a file line by line and trying to mask the text with X character. Please read my updated question. I just edited it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replacing airports with an equal number of Xs

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SFO&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SANFRANSISCO&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHISWITH&DEST=SANJOSE
```

To replace the strings after `&DEST=` with an equal length of `X` and using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E ':a; s/(&DEST=X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' file
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=XXX&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=XXXXXXXXXXXX&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHISWITH&DEST=XXXXXXX
```

To replace the file in-place:

```
sed -i -E ':a; s/(&DEST=X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' file
```

The above was tested with GNU sed.  For BSD (OSX) sed, try:

```
sed -Ee :a -e 's/(&DEST=X*)[^X&]/\1X/' -e ta file
```

Or, to change in-place with BSD(OSX) sed, try:

```
sed -i '' -Ee :a -e 's/(&DEST=X*)[^X&]/\1X/' -e ta file
```

If there is some reason why it is important to use the shell to read the file line-by-line:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   echo "$line" | sed -Ee :a -e 's/(&DEST=X*)[^X&]/\1X/' -e ta
done <file
```

#### How it works

Let's consider this code:

```
search_str="&DEST="
newfile=chart.txt
sed -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"
```

- `-E`

  This tells sed to use Extended Regular Expressions (ERE).  This has the advantage of requiring fewer backslashes to escape things.
- `:a`

  This creates a label `a`.
- `s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X&]/\1X/`

  This looks for `$search_str` followed by any number of `X` followed by any character that is not `X` or `&`.  Because of the parens, everything except that last character is saved into group 1.  This string is replaced by group 1, denoted `\1` and an `X`.
- `ta`

  In sed, `t` is a `test` command.  If the substitution was made (meaning that some character needed to be replaced by `X`), then the test evaluates to true and, in that case, `ta` tells sed to jump to label `a`.

  This test-and-jump causes the substitution to be repeated as many times as necessary.

#### Replacing multiple tags with one sed command

```
$ name='DEST|ORIG'; sed -E ':a; s/(&('"$name"')=X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' file
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=XXX&ORIG=XXXX
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=XXXXXXXXXXXX&ORIG=XXXX
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHISWITH&DEST=XXXXXXX
```

### Answer for original question

#### Using shell

```
$ s='MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SFO&ORIG=6546'
$ s=${s#*&DEST=}
$ echo ${s%%&*}
SFO
```

How it works:

- `${s#*&DEST=}` is *prefix removal*.  This removes all text up to and including the first occurrence of `&DEST=`.
- `${s%%&*}` is suffix removal_.  It removes all text from the first `&` to the end of the string.

### Using awk

```
$ echo 'MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SFO&ORIG=6546' | awk -F'[=\n]' '$1=="DEST"{print $2}' RS='&'
SFO
```

**How it works:**

- `-F'[=\n]'`

  This tells awk to treat either an equal sign or a newline as the field separator
- `$1=="DEST"{print $2}`

  If the first field is DEST, then print the second field.
- `RS='&'`

  This sets the record separator to `&`.

Comment: You might want `${s##*&DEST=}` ? for an i/p say `O8764GETTHIS&DEST&=DEST=SFO&ORIG=6546`. But perhaps that is not valid i/p is it?

Comment: @mona_sax OK.  Could you clarify a bit?  In your example, the string `&DEST=` never occurs.  If that was a typo, do you anticipate cases where `&DEST=` is in the string _twice_?  Why?  If it is in the string twice, how would we know that we wanted the value of the last occurrence (as per your code) and not the first?

Comment: Using shell, I like the solution. Because remember that I am reading a file line by line and if a has say : 'MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SFO&ORIG=6546' than I need to extract SFO and replace it by 3 X characters like: 'MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=XXX&ORIG=6546' and replace the entire line with the modified line.
... If it is SANJOSE, then I need to replace it with 7 'X' character...
....
So, I need something which can give me a modified line.

Comment: Thank you!!. I will try it.
Also, I have edited my question a bit. Could you please read my updated questions? Thanks!!

Comment: @PuneetJain OK.  See updated answer for a method to replace the airports with Xs.

Comment: @John1024, Hi John, in order for your answer "sed -i -E ':a; s/(&DEST=X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' file" to work, what command should i have to read the file line by line. I mean, I can find out from other forums on how to read a file (say chart.txt) line by line, but I am asking your command which can be followed by above mentioned sed command. 
Thanks

Comment: @PuneetJain `sed` is good at reading line-by-line from a file.  In case there is some reason why you need to use shell code to do that instead, I just added sample code for that.

Comment: @John1024 When I am putting &DEST= into a variable, and using it, its not working.

search_str="&DEST=";
newfile=chart.txt;
sed -i -E ':a; s/("$search_str"X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"

Am i missing something else?
Thanks for your help John !!

Comment: Try: `search_str="&DEST="; newfile=chart.txt; sed -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"`

Comment: @John1024 Thanks John !! It worked. If you have time, would you mind telling me different part of the command, what they do etc, in case if I have some requirement change, then I can take your command as base and modify it accordingly. Thanks. Appreciate ur help.

Comment: @PuneetJain OK.  I added an explanation: see the newly added "How it works" section.

Comment: Thanks @John1024 . Sorry if I m bugging you.. but other than of a plain "&DEST=", i have to support "&DEST[7]="... basically square brackets have been added with a arbitray number inside it... and i have to mask the text after the "=" till the next "&".

\n

MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST[3]=XXX&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST[12]=XXXXXXXXXXXX&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHISWITH&DEST[7]=XXXXXXX

Something you can help with if its easy for you!!

Comment: In that case, use `search_str="&DEST(\[[[:digit:]]+\])?="`

Comment: Thanks @John1024. Unfortunately it didn't worked. Both the cases didn't worked......This is what I did..... search_str=\&$name"(\[[[:digit:]]+\])?="
where $name can have values such as DEST or ORIG or HALT etc...

Comment: @John1024 One side effect I am seeing is that if the input is :"&DEST= SFO &"
Than the output is "&DEST=XXXO &" instead of "&DEST= XXX &".... looks like something goof up in space counting.

Comment: @PuneetJain Replace `[^X&]` with `[^X &]` like this: `sed -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X &]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"`

Comment: Thanks @John1024 it worked. Now one final last thing remaining is this-> If you could as well answer it, i would really really appreciate it.. I have search 100s of forums but nothing came close to this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757920/parsing-line-and-changing-some-text-in-place

Comment: @John1024 Hi John... Looks like for the question in the other post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757920/parsing-line-and-changing-some-text-in-place, somehow I am not able to add you to my reply.. not sure why.. so I am replying here, so that you can please answer my last question in that other post. Thanks.

Comment: @John1024 I know I am asking too much, but if you could correct my querry i wrote, i would really appreciate it.. its not working in couple of cases.. see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911200/change-string-in-file-between-two-strings-with-character-x

Comment: @John1024 Coming back to this original questions answer, you said, I can  use this : search_str=\&$name"([[[:digit:]]+])?=" where $name can have different values from an array : like in a while loop, name can have DEST, and then it can have ORIG etc. Its working. But its not efficient, because if there are 10 strings like DEST/NAME/TAXI etc, then the sed command is being called multiple times. Can I write a sed command in which search_str=\&$names"([[[:digit:]]+])?=" and while $name will be (DEST|ORIG|TAXI|PLANE) etc? I tried it, but its not working. Please help.

Comment: @PuneetJain See the section entitled "Replacing multiple tags with one sed command" in the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SFO&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=PORTORICA
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=SANFRANSISCO&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHISWITH&DEST=SANJOSE
$ sed -E 's/^.*&DEST=([^&]*)[&]*.*$/\1/' file
SFO
PORTORICA
SANFRANSISCO
SANJOSE
```

should do it

Comment: Thank you!!. I will try it.
Also, I have edited my question a bit. Could you please read my updated questions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ (.*&DEST=)(.*)((&.*|$)) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}fooooo${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done < file
```

Output:

```
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=fooooo&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHIS&DEST=fooooo&ORIG=6546
MYREQUESTISTO8764GETTHISWITH&DEST=fooooo
```

Comment: Thank you!!. I will try it.
Also, I have edited my question a bit. Could you please read my updated questions? Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Replace the characters between `&DEST` and `&` (or EOL) with x's:

```
awk -F'&DEST='  '{
   printf("%s&DEST=", $1);
   xlen=index($2,"&");
   if ( xlen == 0) xlen=length($2)+1;
   for (i=0;i<xlen;i++) printf("%s", "X");
   endstr=substr($2,xlen);
   printf("%s\n", endstr);
   }' file
```