# Parsing line and changing some text in place

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, sed

How do I parse a log file (not a full xml file, but it has some portion of xml data) for ExtData tags, which has some name-value pair, I need to mask it like this : For eg:

> ```
> <ExtData>Name="Jason" Value="Special"</ExtData>
> to
> <ExtData>Name="Jason" Value="XXXXXXX"</ExtData>
> ```

I need to mask ExtData tag value like above only when Name is Jason or some set of name, and not for every Name.

For eg: if "DummyName" is not in set of names, than I do not want to change this below line.

> ```
> <ExtData>Name="DummyName" Value="Garbage"</ExtData>
> ```

For eg: if "DummyName" is not in set of names, than I do not want to change this below line. (Please note that the value is "Jason")

> ```
> <ExtData>Name="DummyName" Value="Jason"</ExtData>
> ```

For eg: if "DummyJasonName" is not in set of names, than I do not want to change this below line. (Note "Jason" in between "Dummy" and "Name")

> ```
> <ExtData>Name="DummyJasonName" Value="Garbage"</ExtData>
> ```

I need to do all this in bash/shell script.

Bottom line is, I want to read a file, say, via sed/awk/match command.
Check for ExtData tag in the line. If matched, Read the text between ExtData tag and /ExtData tag. In this multiline text, extract Name. If Name is from a set of names, then mask its corresponding "Value" data with equal number of 'X'.

Please let me know how to achieve the above task.

Update, the input line can actually span over multiple lines.

> ```
> <ExtData>Name="Jason" 
> Value="Special"
>     </ExtData>
> ```

Or like this too:

> ```
> <ExtData>
>      Name="Jason" 
>   Value="Special"
>     </ExtData>
> ```

Thanks !! Puneet

Comment: @John1024 Asking known person :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the substitutions only for names Jason and Jim, try:

```
sed -E '/Jason|Jim/{:a; /Value=/bb; n; ba; :b; s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/; tb; }' file.xml
```

This command was tested on GNU sed.  For BSD/OSX sed, some minor changes would be needed.

#### Example

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file.xml
<ExtData>Name="Jason" Value="Special"</ExtData>
<ExtData>Name="DummyName" Value="Garbage"</ExtData>
<ExtData>Name="Jim"
    Value="OK"
        </ExtData>
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ sed -E '/Jason|Jim/{:a; /Value=/bb; n; ba; :b; s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/; tb; }' file.xml
<ExtData>Name="Jason" Value="XXXXXXX"</ExtData>
<ExtData>Name="DummyName" Value="Garbage"</ExtData>
<ExtData>Name="Jim"
    Value="XX"
        </ExtData>
```

#### How it works

- `-E`

  This tells set to use extended regular expressions.
- `/Jason|Jim/{...}`

  This tells sed to run the commands inside the curly braces only for lines that contain Jason or Jim.   The command insides the braces breaks down into two parts:

  1. `:a; /Value=/bb; n; ba;`

     The first part reads lines until we find one that contains `Value=`.  In more detail, `:a` defines a label `a`.  `/Value=/bb` branches to label `b` if the current line contains `Value=`.  If it doesn't, we print out the current line and read in the next one using the `n` command.  We then branch (`b`)  back to label `a`.
  2. `:b; s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/; tb;`

     This replaces the value with as many `X` as we need.

     In more detail, `:b` defines a label `b`.  `s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/` substitutes in the next `X` that we need after `Value=`.  If a substitution was made (meaning that another `X` was needed), then the test command (`t`) tells sed to jump back to label `b` and we try again.

#### Restricting changes to within ExtData tags

Let's consider this more complex test file:

```
$ cat file2.xml
<Misc>Name="Jason" Value="DontChange"</Misc>
<ExtData>Name="Jason" Value="Special"</ExtData>
<Misc>Name="Jason" Value="DontChange"</Misc>
<ExtData>Name="DummyName" Value="DontChange"</ExtData>
<Misc>Name="Jason" Value="DontChange"</Misc>
<ExtData>Name="Jim"
    Value="OK"
        </ExtData>
<Misc>Name="Jason" Value="DontChange"</Misc>
```

To make the changes in ExtData tags but not the other tags, try:

```
$ sed -E '/[<]ExtData[>]/{:a; /Name=/{/Name="(Jason|Jim)"/!b}; /Value=/bb; n; ba; :b; s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/; tb; }' file2.xml
<Misc>Name="Jason" Value="DontChange"</Misc>
<ExtData>Name="Jason" Value="XXXXXXX"</ExtData>
<Misc>Name="Jason" Value="DontChange"</Misc>
<ExtData>Name="DummyName" Value="DontChange"</ExtData>
<Misc>Name="Jason" Value="DontChange"</Misc>
<ExtData>Name="Jim"
    Value="XX"
        </ExtData>
<Misc>Name="Jason" Value="DontChange"</Misc>
```

To do the above using a shell variable for the names:

```
names='Jason|Jim'
sed -E '/[<]ExtData[>]/{:a; /Name=/{/Name="'"$names"'"/!b}; /Value=/bb; n; ba; :b; s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/; tb; }' file2.xml
```

This substitutes the shell variable directly into the `sed` command.  This should only be done this way if you trust the source of the shell variable.

Comment: Thanks. . I knew you would give me a perfact answer... I am very new to scripting, and your responses have surely helped me. 
Just to clarify, I have preset list of Names like this : declare -a NameList=(Jason Jim) and so forth... So based on ur solution, I should loop through each name in the NameList, and use $name in the sed command like this : sed -i -E '/"$name"/{:a; /Value=/bb; n; ba; :b; s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/; tb; }' file.xml including "-i" because I need to change the file content in place.... Thanks once again....

Comment: One more thing I noticed that This name value pair should be inside ExtData and /ExtData tags.... Because Jason name and/or Jim name can also be found as part of normal text in the log file.

Comment: John, pls let me know. Thanks !!

Comment: @PuneetJain Does the complete string `Name="Jason"` appear outside of the `ExtData` tags?  Or, is it just `Jason` which might appear outside those tags?

Comment: @PuneetJain OK.  I just came up with an idea and added it to the answer.  Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you @John1024. I will try and let you know the result.
I hope your command works on this too...

< <ExtData>Name="Jason" Value="Change"</ExtData><ExtData>
<     Name="Jim" 
< Value="Change"
<   </ExtData>

Comment: Thanks @John1024 your solution worked like a charm.... Now w.r.t to xml tag, only 1 simple thing (for you) remains... thats it.. and I will be done... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911200/change-string-in-file-between-two-strings-with-character-x see if u have a look at it. No body gave me a perfact solution yet on it yet? Thanks again John !!

Comment: Thanks @John1024 your solution worked like a charm.... Now w.r.t to xml tag, only 1 simple thing (for you) remains... thats it.. and I will be done... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911200/change-string-in-file-between-two-strings-with-character-x see if u have a look at it. No body gave me a perfact solution yet on it yet? Thanks again John !!

Comment: An easy one for you John : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911200/change-string-in-file-between-two-strings-with-character-x @John1024

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm, until i saw a line which was masked too which it was not supposed to mask. For example, <ExtData>Name="DummyName" Value="Garbage"</ExtData> line should not masked and it is not masked. Which is correct. But suppose,  if the line has "Jason" any where in the line, than also it is being masked. <ExtData>Name="DummyName" Value="Jason"</ExtData> is being masked, <ExtData>Name="DummyJasonName" Value="Garbage"</ExtData> is also being masked.

Comment: you there John? @John2014

Answer (score 1):

In a bash shell, you can create a copy of the file with the info removed using this

```
sed 's#\(<ExtData>Name="Jason" Value="\).*\("</ExtData>\)#\1XXXXX\2#' xml.txt > xml_xxx.txt
```

Note that it's not the "official" way to change a xml file. Lots of format changes could occur that would render this script useless, but if you know that your XML file has 1 info per line formatted like that, it will work, exactly like for a text file and it's quick.

(also the question is tagged sed and bash, if it wasn't that would involve heavy xml parsing using `libxml2`, `saxon` or other libraries that can parse XML nodes)

Comment: Thanks @jean-françois-fabre I see that you have hardcoded Jason and XXXXX. This might work for this particular line, but as I mentioned previously, the name is retrived from an array. list_of_names_which_needs_value_changed (Jason Jack Alter Viktoria ....................... 100 names). So I don't want to change for every name, just the names which are present in list_of_names_which_needs_value_changed array... and also, Their value can be of arbitary size, and not fixed to 5 characters. Also, there can be spaces bw ExtData tag and Name, bw Name and Value and finally bw Value and /ExtData.