# change string in file between two strings with character X

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I wanna replace value between a tag by equal number of X. For example

1.

```
<Name> Jason </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX </Name>
```

2.
 (see no space)

```
 <Name>Jim</Name>
 to
 <Name>XXX</Name>
```

3.

```
<Name Jason /> 
to 
<Name XXXXX />`
```

4.

```
<Name Jas />
to
<Name XXX />
```

starting tag, value and closing tag can all come in different line

5.

```
<Name>Jim
</Name>
to
<Name>XXX
</Name>
```

6.

```
<Name>
     Jim
       </Name>
to
<Name>
     XXX
       </Name>
```

7.

```
  <Name
     Jim
       />
to
  <Name
     XXX
       />
```

8.

```
<Name> Jason </Name> <Name> Ignacio </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX </Name> <Name> XXXXXX </Name>
```

9.

```
<Name> Jason Ignacio </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX XXXXXXX </Name>
or
<Name> XXXXXXXXXXXXX </Name>
```

both are fine

I tried this, but it didn't worked

```
file=mylog.log
search_str="<Name>"
end_str="</Name>"
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X'"$end_str"']/\1X/; ta' "$file"
```

Please let me know how to do this in bash script....

Update:

I tried this also, but didn't worked for 6 and 7 cases. case 1 to 5 worked.

```
sed -i -E '/<Name>/{:a; /<\/Name>/bb; n; ba; :b; s/(<Name>X*)[^X\<]/\1X/; tb; }' "$file"
sed -i -E '/<Name[[:space:]]/{:a; /\/>/bb; n; ba; :b; s/(<Name[[:space:]]X*)[^X\/]/\1X/; tb; }' "$file"
```

Comment: Suggest using an `xml` aware tool (or) tools which are able to parse `<node>` elements. `sed` or `awk` is not the best way for the same

Comment: It can be done, but it is going to be painful for each case.  I'm not willing to undergo the pain involved in producing the answer.  Cases 3 & 4 look to be identical.  Cases 1 & 2 can be handled with a regex along the lines of `s/\(<Name>[[:space:]]*X*\)\([^X[:space:]]\)\([[:space:]]*<\/Name>\)/\1X\2/` and some `sed` hackery to iterate until there are no substitutions (a label and a test/branch operation).  Note that the mechanism shown won't deal with `<Name> Jason Bourne </Name>` — you have some changes to make (easy ones, as it happens).  Have fun.

Comment: Incidentally, if you can have `<Name> Jason Bourne </Name>`, should the output be `<Name> XXXXX XXXXXX </Name>` or `<Name> XXXXXXXXXXXX </Name>`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler since given `v="Jason"` and `echo "${v//?/X}"` returns XXXXX, wouldn't using `sed` to perform this parameter expansion like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34080390/1983854) help? I find it difficult to use parameter expansion against a captured group, though.

Comment: @fedorqui: I'm guessing that the names are not just Jason, Jim, Jas, in general.  And a single chunk of XML could have a myriad different names — I'm envisaging XML output of a customer table with names masked, for example.  So I think anything that uses shell to find a value and do the substitution is going to be painful — but the whole exercise is going to be painful regardless.  You really need an XML parser (Perl, Python, ...) and to process it that way.

Comment: @Inian The problem is, `<Name Jim />` is not valid XML.

Comment: My regex was a bit off.  `sed -e ': l1' -e
's/\(<Name>[[:space:]]*X*\)\([^X[:space:]]\)\(.*[[:space:]]*<\/Name>\)/\1X\3/'
-e 't l1'` deals with single word names where the start and end tag are on the same line.  It does handle the case where there are two complete name entries on a single line.  I take it back; adapting that to handle multi-word names is not straight-forward, regardless of whether embedded blanks should be retained or mapped to `X` too.  You probably need code around that to detect that you've got the single line case so you can try the multi-line cases separately.

Comment: If you need to handle a line with case 1 and, say, case 6 starting on the same line, things get still more fraught.  Any regex-based solution will be fragile — only a proper parsing solution is going to be reliable.  (See [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/))

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Multi word with in a tag is fine. "Mike Author" can be replaced either by "XXXX XXXXXX" or by "XXXXXXXXXXX". does not really matter.

Comment: @John1024 Adding john to get his inputs !!

Answer (score 3):

### Provisional solution

This extends the 'initial offering' below and handles cases 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9.  It does not handle the case where there is one or more complete `<Name>…</Name>` entries and also a starting `<Name>` without the matching `</Name>` on the same line.  Frankly, I'm not even sure how to start tackling that scenario.

The unhandled cases 3, 4, 7 are not valid XML — I'm not convinced they're valid HTML (or XHTML) either.  I believe they can be handled by a similar (but simpler) mechanism to the one shown here for the full `<Name>…</Name>` version.  I'm leaving that as an exercise for the reader (beware the `<` in the character class — it would need to become a `/`).

#### `script.sed`

```
/<Name>/! b
/<Name>.*<\/Name>/{
: l1
s/\(<Name>[[:space:]]*\(X[X[[:space:]]*\)\{0,1\}\)[^X<[:space:]]\(.*[[:space:]]*<\/Name>\)/\1X\3/
t l1
b
}
/<Name>/,/<\/Name>/{
  # Handle up to 4 lines to the end-name tag
  /<\/Name>/! N
  /<\/Name>/! N
  /<\/Name>/! N
  /<\/Name>/! N
# s/^/ZZ/; s/$/AA/p
# s/^ZZ//; s/AA$//
  : l2
  s/\(<Name>[[:space:]]*\(X[X[[:space:]]*\)\{0,1\}\)[^X<[:space:]]\(.*[[:space:]]*<\/Name>\)/\1X\3/
  t l2
}
```

The first line 'skips' processing of lines not containing `<Name>` (they get printed and the next line is read).  The next 6 lines are the script from the 'initial offering' except that there's a `b` to jump to the end of processing.

The new section is the `/<Name>/,/<\/Name>/` code.  This looks for `<Name>` on its own, and concatenates up to 4 lines until a `</Name>` is included in the pattern space.  The two comment lines were used for debugging — they allowed me to see what was being treated as a unit.  Except for the use of the label `l2` in place of `l1`, the remainder is exactly the same as in the initial offering — `sed` regexes already accommodate newlines.

This is heavy-duty `sed` scripting and not what I'd want to use or maintain.  I would go with a Perl solution using an XML parser (because I know Perl better than Python), but Python would do the job fine too with an appropriate XML parser.

#### `data`

A slightly extended data file.

```
<Name> Jason </Name>
<Name>Jim</Name>
<Name> Jason Bourne </Name>
<Name> Elijah </Name> <Name> Dennis </Name>
<Name> Elijah Wood </Name> <Name> Dennis The Menace </Name>
<Name>Elijah Wood</Name> <Name>Dennis The Menace</Name>
<Name> Jason
        </Name>
<Name>
    Jim</Name>
<Name>
    Jim
        </Name>
<Name> Jason
Bourne </Name>
<Name> 
    Jason
        Bourne
            </Name>
<Name> Elijah </Name>
<Name>
Dennis
</Name>
<Name> Elijah
Wood </Name>
            <Name> Dennis
The Menace </Name>
<Name>Elijah
Wood</Name>
    <Name>Dennis The
Menace</Name>



<Name> Jason </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX </Name>

2. (see no space)

 <Name>Jim</Name>
 to
 <Name>XXX</Name>

3.

<!--Name Jason /--> 
to 
<!--Name XXXXX /-->`

4.

<!--Name Jas /-->
to
<!--Name XXX /-->

starting tag, value and closing tag can all come in different line

5.

<Name>Jim
</Name>
to
<Name>XXX
</Name>

6.

<Name>
     Jim
       </Name>
to
<Name>
     XXX
       </Name>

7.

  <!--Name
     Jim
       /-->
to
  <!--Name
     XXX
       /-->

8.

<Name> Jason </Name> <Name> Ignacio </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX </Name> <Name> XXXXXX </Name>

9.

<Name> Jason Ignacio </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX XXXXXXX </Name>
or
<Name> XXXXXXXXXXXXX </Name>
```

No claims are made that the `data` file contains a minimal set of cases; it is repetitious.  It includes the material from the question, except that the 'unorthodox' XML elements like `<Name Value />` are converted into XML comments `<!--Name Value /-->`.  The mapping actually isn't crucial; the opening part doesn't match `<Name>` (and the tail doesn't match `</Name>`) so they'd not be processed anyway.

#### Output

```
$ sed -f script.sed data
<Name> XXXXX </Name>
<Name>XXX</Name>
<Name> XXXXX XXXXXX </Name>
<Name> XXXXXX </Name> <Name> XXXXXX </Name>
<Name> XXXXXX XXXX </Name> <Name> XXXXXX XXX XXXXXX </Name>
<Name>XXXXXX XXXX</Name> <Name>XXXXXX XXX XXXXXX</Name>
<Name> XXXXX
        </Name>
<Name>
    XXX</Name>
<Name>
    XXX
        </Name>
<Name> XXXXX
XXXXXX </Name>
<Name> 
    XXXXX
        XXXXXX
            </Name>
<Name> XXXXXX </Name>
<Name>
XXXXXX
</Name>
<Name> XXXXXX
XXXX </Name>
            <Name> XXXXXX
XXX XXXXXX </Name>
<Name>XXXXXX
XXXX</Name>
    <Name>XXXXXX XXX
XXXXXX</Name>



<Name> XXXXX </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX </Name>

2. (see no space)

 <Name>XXX</Name>
 to
 <Name>XXX</Name>

3.

<!--Name Jason /--> 
to 
<!--Name XXXXX /-->`

4.

<!--Name Jas /-->
to
<!--Name XXX /-->

starting tag, value and closing tag can all come in different line

5.

<Name>XXX
</Name>
to
<Name>XXX
</Name>

6.

<Name>
     XXX
       </Name>
to
<Name>
     XXX
       </Name>

7.

  <!--Name
     Jim
       /-->
to
  <!--Name
     XXX
       /-->

8.

<Name> XXXXX </Name> <Name> XXXXXXX </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX </Name> <Name> XXXXXX </Name>

9.

<Name> XXXXX XXXXXXX </Name>
to
<Name> XXXXX XXXXXXX </Name>
or
<Name> XXXXXXXXXXXXX </Name>
$
```

---

### Initial offering

A partial answer — but it illustrates the problems you face.  Dealing with cases 1 & 2 in the question, plus the multi-word variations, you can use the script:

#### `script.sed`

```
/<Name>.*<\/Name>/{
: l1
s/\(<Name>[[:space:]]*\(X[X[[:space:]]*\)\{0,1\}\)[^X<[:space:]]\(.*[[:space:]]*<\/Name>\)/\1X\3/
t l1
}
```

That is pretty contorted, to be polite about it.  It looks for `<Name>` followed by zero or more spaces.  That can be followed by `\(X[X[[:space:]]*\)\{0,1\}`, which means zero or one occurrences of an X followed by a sequence of X's or spaces.  All of that is captured as `\1` in the replacement.  Then there's a single character that isn't an `X`, `<` or space, followed by zero or more any characters, zero or more spaces, and `</Name>`.  The single character in the middle is replaced by an X.  The whole replacement is repeated until there are no more matches via the label `: l1` and the conditional branch `t l1`.  All that operates only on a line with both `<Name>` and `</Name>`.

#### `data`

```
<Name> Jason </Name>
<Name>Jim</Name>
<Name> Jason Bourne </Name>
<Name> Elijah </Name> <Name> Dennis </Name>
<Name> Elijah Wood </Name> <Name> Dennis The Menace </Name>
<Name>Elijah Wood</Name> <Name>Dennis The Menace</Name>
<Name> Jason
</Name>
<Name>
Jim</Name>
<Name> Jason
Bourne </Name>
<Name> Elijah </Name> <Name> Dennis
</Name>
<Name> Elijah
Wood </Name> <Name> Dennis
The Menace </Name>
<Name>Elijah
Wood</Name> <Name>Dennis The
Menace</Name>
```

#### Output

```
$ sed -f script.sed data
<Name> XXXXX </Name>
<Name>XXX</Name>
<Name> XXXXX XXXXXX </Name>
<Name> XXXXXX </Name> <Name> XXXXXX </Name>
<Name> XXXXXX XXXX </Name> <Name> XXXXXX XXX XXXXXX </Name>
<Name>XXXXXX XXXX</Name> <Name>XXXXXX XXX XXXXXX</Name>
<Name> Jason
</Name>
<Name>
Jim</Name>
<Name> Jason
Bourne </Name>
<Name> XXXXXX </Name> <Name> Dennis
</Name>
<Name> Elijah
Wood </Name> <Name> Dennis
The Menace </Name>
<Name>Elijah
Wood</Name> <Name>Dennis The
Menace</Name>
$
```

Note the replacement part way through the end.  That line is going to cause headaches for anything more.

I've not worked out how the script would handle the various split-line cases, beyond it would almost certainly need to join lines until the `</Name>` is caught.  It would then do processing closely related to that already shown, but it would need to allow for newlines in the matched material.

Comment: Thanks... I will give your solution a try, but i really need to multi-line solution, specially case 6.

Answer (score 1):

Try this python script:

```
$ cat script.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('allcases'), features="xml")
for tag in soup.findAll('Name'):
    for name in 'Jason Ignacio', 'Jason', 'Jim':
        tag.string =  re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % name, len(name)*'X', tag.string)
print(str(soup))
```

This code is compatible with either python2 or python3.

To make it work, you may need to install the BeautifulSoup module.  On a debian-like system:

```
apt-get install python-bs4
```

Or, for python3:

```
apt-get install python3-bs4
```

#### Example

Let's consider this input file:

```
$ cat cases
<page>
<p>Jason</p>
<Name> Jason </Name>
<p>Jason</p>
 <Name>Jim</Name>
<p>Jim</p>
<Name>Jim
</Name>
<Name>
     Jim
       </Name>
<Name> Jason </Name> <Name> Ignacio </Name>
<Name> Jason Ignacio </Name>
</page>
```

Let's run our script and observe the output:

```
$ python script.py
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<page>
<p>Jason</p>
<Name> XXXXX </Name>
<p>Jason</p>
<Name>XXX</Name>
<p>Jim</p>
<Name>XXX
</Name>
<Name>
     XXX
       </Name>
<Name> XXXXX </Name> <Name> Ignacio </Name>
<Name> XXXXXXXXXXXXX </Name>
</page>
```

Note that the names in `<p>` tags are left alone.  The code only changes the names in `<Name>` tags.

Also, as per the design, `Jim`, `Jason`, and `Jason Ignacio` are changed to X's but other names are left alone.  Even Ignacio, if it appears without an adjacent Jason, is left alone.

Comment: Thanks @John1024. This is exactly the result i want.. however on our server, there is no python.. only shell/bash.. Do you mind giving me an equivalent sed command... or may be tell me whats wrong in my sed command ?

Comment: Hey john @John1024 .. Do you know how to fix case 6/7 using sed command?

Comment: @PuneetJain Would you clarify one point: are looking to change only specific names?  Or, do you want to change all alphabetic characters that occur inside the Name tags?

Comment: John @John1024 Anything inside the Name tag. Name is just 1 word shown here.. In reality i would be using a variable, whose value would come from name array like : (John, Jim, Carry, Marry, SSN, Dude) etc..
Currently I am using 2 sed command : 
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str1"'X*)[^X\<]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str2"'X*)[^X\/]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"

But they are not working for multiline cases, like #6 and #7 case.
Also, i would really like to combine these 2 sed commands into one, if possible.

Comment: HELLOOOOO!! u there? @John1024