# How to get data from grepped string?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I need to get data from grepped string, but I'm kind of newbie.

I have grepped data string like this:

```
email=test@mail.com&id=12451233&name=Susanna&surname=Scott&street=East
```

I need to parse email, id, name and surname from this.

Tried to grep like this:

```
sed -e 's/email\ \(.*\)&id/\1/'
```

Nothing happens (need to do it using sed)
Displaying data one under another is second step

expected format:

```
test@mail.ru|12451233|Susanna|Scott
```

Comment: `... | tr '&' '\n'`

Comment: `sed -e 's/&/\n/g'`?

Comment: @Jane It would be helpful if you could outline the expected output format as well!

Comment: Yes, I displays data correct. But in this case I don't need whole data, because there are some more unnecessary fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse $QUERY\_STRING from a bash CGI script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919755/how-to-parse-query-string-from-a-bash-cgi-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sed answer - simple but gets the job done:

```
sed -e 's/email=//' -e 's/&id=/ /' -e 's/&name=/ /' -e 's/&surname=/ /' -e 's/&street=.*//'
```

Reviewing the question, i just discovered you are looking for pipe delimited output.  Well, here is the slightly modified sed script for piped output:

```
sed -e 's/email=//' -e 's/&id=/|/' -e 's/&name=/|/' -e 's/&surname=/|/' -e 's/&street=.*//'
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. For education purposes: f.e. if there will be an unnecessary field between email and id, how can I remove it?

Comment: Add a -e (edit) command to the command.  &street is already an example for deleting an unnecessary field (well, it is a bit harsh, since it deletes EVERYTHING after the &street token.   You can delete a specific token like this `-e 's/&trash=[^&]*//' ` which deletes everything from &trash to the next &.  Or if you want to delete everything from email to &id, you can try this:  `-e 's/email=.*&id/&id/'` - basically the s command I keep using is s/find/replace/.

Comment: Thanks! One more if it's not difficult enough: Is it possible to change order of displayed parts? Surname->name->phone->id f.e.

Comment: Awk can easily rearrange the results.   Try piping it to ` awk `{print $4,$3,$2,$1}'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`

```
awk -F "=|&" '{print $2, $4, $6, $8}'
```

`-F` is the feldseperator, in your case they are `=` or(`|`) `&` and then just print the columns.

Comment: Yes, it displays what I need, but problem is in awk: I'm not the only work who works with bash script and it is little bigger request that I displayed, that's why I asked for help with sed)

Comment: Ok, than try the answer from @Mark